# SharePoint 2010 document Library - Permission based on column value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

### I have a document library which includes "department" column amongst others. My requirement is

•  Assign permission in the document upload process depending on which department should have access to this document

• Depending on which department a user belongs and also what permission the user has, the view of the document library should be filtered to the documents the user has access to rather than showing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a permission based on column, it's best to eliminate that column, and put it into folders instead to make a true level of security. Then uninherit the permissions for each folder, to make permission changes to it.

Then assign a view that, in the folder section, "Displays all items inside folders", to be able to have a user view only what he/she has access to.

Comment: Thanks Mike, What about if I want to give the user uploading the document set the permission based on the list of permission group list in the site? Can I have that feature some how available in the uploading modal dialog?

Comment: he/she will only have permission to upload to that folder, but it should specify which folder he/she would like to upload to. http://media.wiley.com/Lux/23/290323.image0.jpg

Comment: +1 folders are usually not a good idea in SharePoint, but this scenario is the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally we can't set permission in column level, but we can do a work around.
We can have a custom form and using jquery we can hide/show the columns depending on the permission level we can set. Using jquery you can check which group the user belongs and then depending on the user permission hide or show the field/s.

-Vikram

Comment: Thanks Vikram but my question is a little different. I have 10 departments and I created a permission group for each department using code(Feature), broke the permission inheritance from the parent site for this document library and now I want to give the user an option to assign permission group for the document s/he is uploading?                               I appreciate your help and let me know if it is not still clear what I am trying to accomplish...

Comment: You can create a 'Public View' on the Document Library and make it 'default' or you can modify the default view 'All items' and add a filter.

In the view : create a filter on "created by"  = [Me]. It will only show the items which are created by the logged-in user.